# Is $\mathbb{R}^4$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2$, $\mathbb{R}^4$ isomorphic to $\mathrm{Mat}_{4 \times 4}(\mathbb{R})$ as $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces?

Tags: matrices, group-isomorphism

- Is $\mathbb{R}^4$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2$ as $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces?
- Is $\mathbb{R}^4$ isomorphic to $\mathrm{Mat}_{4 \times 4}(\mathbb{R})$ as $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces?

For the first one, I can define an isomorphism : $\phi:\mathbb{R}^4→\mathbb{C}^2$ as follows:

$$\phi(a,b,c,d)=(a+bi , c+di)$$

This map is linear and bijective, so it is an isomorphism. Is there any better way to think about this as an isomorphism?

The second statement:

$\mathbb{R}^4$ is a 4-dimensional vector space, the $\mathrm{Mat}_{4 \times 4}(\mathbb{R})$ space, consisting of $4 \times 4$ matrices with real entries. Should the dimensionality of $\mathrm{Mat}_{4 \times 4}(\mathbb{R})$ be regarded as $4$, analogous to $\mathbb{R}^4$, or as $16$, considering the total number of real entries in the matrices?

I'm unsure if this is isomorphic and how I can show it.

Comment: It is $16$ dimensional.

Comment: The set of all $4\times4$ matrices is a real vector space of dimension $16$, so not isomorphic to ${\bf R}^4$. It is not hard to find more than four linearly independent elements of the matrix space.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) to format your posts. Additionally, don't put images in your posts where there could be text.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Comparing $\mathbb R$-dimensions the results follow, since each finite-dimensional $\mathbb R$-vector space $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{\text{dim}_{\mathbb R}(V)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathbb{C}^2$ is correct, they are isomorphic.

But note $\mathrm{Mat}_{4 \times 4}(\mathbb{R})$ is $16$-dimensional. Why is that? Since they are $4 \times 4$ matrices, there are $16$ entries in the matrix, which all correspond to a dimension of the vector space if we choose a certain basis - namely the matrices who are zero in all but one entry.